# Django and PHP together with lighttpd?

Tags: php, django, wordpress, lighttpd

I'm playing around with Django and have built my personal homepage in Django, but I want to use my wordpress blog as a path.

For example if I want to path `/blog/` in Django or in lighttpd so it will render the PHP wordpress site what is the best way to do that?

I tested with proxy.server in lighttpd with no luck - it seems like Django overrides the lightttpd's alias.

```
proxy.server = ("blog/" =>
                ((
                   "host" => "123.123.123.123",
                   "port" => 80
                ))
               )
```

It would be no problem just to let blog.testsite.com go to an lighttpd instance which will render the PHP, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it

just under the defining of $HTTP["host"]

```
proxy.server = ( "blog/" =>
               ( (
                   "host" => "123.123.123.111",
                   "port" => 80
                 ) )
           )
```

and in url rewrite-once i added "^(/blog.*)$" => "$1",

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^(/blog.*)$" => "$1",
)
```

I hope this willhelp someone